# how do you change the tint color of an unselected image in a tab bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

How do you change the tint color of an unselected image in a tab bar in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that. There was a feature allowing you to do that, but it was removed in iOS 7 and has never been restored.

Your only option, if you want that kind of control, is not to use the tint color at all, but to set the image and the selected image, as normal images (rendered using `AlwaysOriginal`, not template images). That way, there's no tinting, and the selected image is used when the item is selected, and the regular image is used when it is not, and the colors are completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can can set the tab bar image tint color for the selected image programmatically, then if you want to tint the unselected image you should make the image yourself with the desired color. I like to do the same color as my selected image but with 50% opacity. The code looks like this:

```
UIImage *item2Image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"simulatorTabBarIconUnselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *item2ImageSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"simulatorTabBarIconSelected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Simulator" image:item2Image selectedImage:item2ImageSelected];
```

The always rendering mode UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal means the unselected image will appear as it is in your image assets folder, whereas the UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate will cause the image to appear as the tint color you've specified. You can see how this looks here:

http://www.apppicker.com/apps/1059513718/jetfuel-by-beaconsinspace